# Tag for analgesics

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [analgesic-pain-killer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analgesic-pain-killer). Outside of Medical Sciences SE, I had never seen a tag whose name contains a synonym.

1. Why not tag [analgesic](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analgesic) with synonym [pain-killer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain-killer)? In other words, the medical term derived from Greek as tag name, the vernacular term as synonym.
2. Or, since we have tags [medications](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medications), [antibiotics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antibiotics), [antivirals](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antivirals), for the sake of consistency, why not use the plural and have tag [analgesics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analgesics) with synonym [pain-killers](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain-killers)?

Comment: Option (2) sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed *analgesic-pain-killer* to *analgesics* and created the synonym *pain-killers* for it. The *pain-killers* synonym still needs to be upvoted to go into effect.